# Solving system of nonlinear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have a system of 4 equations, 4 unknown (A,B,C,D), how would you solve it analytically, assuming a, b, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, F, G, H, I are just some constants?  If using Gaussian Elimination, the lhs matrix would be 8x8 and the vector would be 8x1?

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
A &cos(bx)  &+  B cos(ax)  &+   C &sin(ax) &= F\\
C_1 A &sin(bx)  &+ C_2 B sin(ax)  &+ C_3 C &cos(ax) &= G\\
B &cos((1-b)x) &+     C sin((1-a)x) &- D &cos(bx) &= H\\
C_4 B &sin((1-a)x) &+ C_5 C cos((1-a)x)& + C_6 D &sin(bx) &= I\\
\end{array} 
\right. $$

Comment: The matrix would be $4\times 4$.

Comment: Is $x$ an unknown too?

Answer (score 0):

The system is linear.

$$ \begin{vmatrix} \cos(b x) & \cos(a x) & \sin(a x) & 0 \\
C_1 \sin(b x) & C_2 \sin(a x) & C_3 \cos(a x) & 0 \\
0 & \cos((1-b) x) & \sin((1-a) x) & -\cos(b x) \\
0 & C_4 \sin((1-a)x) & C_5 \cos((1-a) x) & C_6 \sin(b x) \end{vmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} A \\ B \\ C \\ D \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} F \\ G \\ H \\ I \end{pmatrix} $$

Answer (score 0):

Use inverse matrix, I suggest Mathematica or Maple.

You can form

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(bx) & \cos(ax) & \sin (ax) & 0 \\ C_1 \sin(bx) & C_2 \sin(ax) & C_2 \cos(ax) & 0 \\ 0 & \cos((1-b)x) & sin((1-a)x) & -\cos(bx) \\ 0 & C_4 \sin((1-a)x & C_5 \cos((1-a)x) & C_6 \sin(bx)
\end{bmatrix} \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
A\\B\\C\\D
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}F\\G\\H\\I \end{bmatrix}$$

Do the inverse process in the software, then you'll get what you want